# Структура базы данных

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Я хочу реализовать приложение для индексации удаленных данных с последующим доступом к ним в соответствии с наличием определенных прав. По факту - на сервере куча файлов/папок с содержательными названиями (предмет, группа). Студенты/преподаватели вводят пару логин-пароль и получают к ним доступ.
Индексированные данные хранятся в таблице иерархической структуры с первичным ключем- уникальный идентификатор положения каждого узла в списке. Так же имеются поля название файла, расширение, путь к файлу.
Нужно в соответствии к этой таблице сделать таблицу пользователей базы.
Поделитесь идеями, как это дело можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

В статье рассматривается подобная проблема и предложены несколько её вариантов решения:
[Разграничение доступа](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/treedb2.htm#access).